# Trying to find the null columns in the DataFrame and extract them as a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

So I am using this code on my dataframe to figure out which columns have NaN value

```
type(df)
>>pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

df.isna().any()
```

And the error message I get is

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isna'
```

Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try `df.isnull().any()` .

If you want to print the column names:

```
ind=df.columns[df.isnull().any()]
for i in range(len(ind)):
    print ind[i]
```

Comment: @Victor that is an entirely different question, the comment section is not a good place for answering that. Please ask it in a different thread so that other users can also benefit from it.